# How can I assign a custom classloader to a module layer in Java?

Tags: java, security, plugins, module, classloader

Following the wake of JEP 411, I am trying to create a simple sandbox in Java for loading untrusted code.

Unfortunately, I am unfamiliar with the module system and it seems I cannot get my created module layer to use my custom class loader when loading module classes.

I have tried creating the module layer and used the method `defineModulesWithOneLoader` to assign my custom class loader, however, this does not seem to use my custom class loader.

Here is the following code I am using:

Main

```java
        String moduleName = "somemodule";
        Path dir = Path.of("./path/to/somemodule/");
        ModuleFinder finder = ModuleFinder.of(pluginDirectory);
        ModuleLayer parent = ModuleLayer.boot();
        Configuration conf = parent.configuration().resolve(finder, ModuleFinder.of(), Set.of(moduleName));
        ClassLoader classLoader = new CustomClassLoader();
        ModuleLayer layer = parent.defineModulesWithOneLoader(config, classLoader);
        Class<?> c = layer.findLoader("somemodule").loadClass("com.example.foo.MyClass");
        System.out.println(c.getClassLoader().getName()); // this does not return the expected classloader, but returns null, indicating the boot layer was used (i think).
```

custom classloader

```java
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        throw new ClassNotFoundException("Custom class loader was used");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should learn more about modules before attempting this. There may be other issues that you need to address.

Comment: [`ModuleLayer#defineModules(Configuration, Function<String, ClassLoader>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html#defineModules(java.lang.module.Configuration,java.util.function.Function)).

Comment: The class loader you pass to `defineModulesWithOneLoader` and `defineModulesWithManyLoaders` is used as the _parent_ of a class loader created as part of the implementation. If you want to fully customize the class loader used by each module, use the method I linked previously.

Comment: One last question, @Slaw, as you know, I'm essentially just being a middleman to check if classes should be loaded or not. If I wish to load the plugin class, I notice that calling `super.loadClass(name, resolve)` inside the overided `loadClass` method of the WhitelistClassLoader does not seem to find the class. When using this approach, is class loading delegation no longer occurring? (Thanks again, and apologies for the ignorance)

Comment: So, the problem is `*WithOneLoader` and `*WithManyLoaders` create their own class loader implementation (with the one you pass used as its parent). This class loader is capable of searching the modules in the configuration. When you use `defineModules(Configuration, Function)`, that internal implementation of class loader is no longer used. In other words, the class loader you pass to `defineModules` needs to be able to find classes in the modules, in addition to filtering which classes are allowed to be loaded.

Comment: You can see the internal class loader implementation [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/547a8b40b324917e66c71409b31421feacce79d7/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/loader/Loader.java#L87). Note it does things a little differently than a purely class-path-based loader. From what I understand, it first looks in the current `Configuration` (i.e., the current `ModuleLayer`), then it looks at the _parent_ `ModuleLayer`s (based on module readability), and only then, if the class wasn't found in a named module, does it delegate to the parent `ClassLoader`.

Comment: I don't know if you'd need to implement the same behavior to be "compliant".

Comment: Thanks for the info, I ended up implementing my own classloader to manually load the required classes from there in the `loadClass` method. Good idea to have a look at the internal class loader implementation too. My next step is to add a service loader to the equation so I'm not dealing with the Object class or unnecessary reflection

Comment: @Slaw the implementation does not try alternatives one after another. The package name of the class to load does already define the owner module. This might be a named module of the current layer or a parent layer, but there’s no ambiguity allowed here, so the lookup structures are already prepared at class loader construction time. If the package name belongs to a known (named) module, only that module’s source is queried and if no class has been found there, it will fail. Only the loading of classes whose packages do not belong to a known named module will be delegated to the parent loader.

Comment: @Holger Sorry, that's actually what I meant in my head while I was writing my comment. Didn't mean to imply otherwise. Thanks for clarifying.